# type or namespace, or end-of-file expected

Tags: c#, console-application

After looking up this error, i can't quite seem to figure out what the problem is, it is probably something small, but it is really bugging me.

It comes up with 2 errors.

} expected line 11 column 10

Type or namespace, or end-of-file expected line 21 column 1

here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Beetlegeuse_intrusion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            public void init()
            {
                weapon testWeapon = new weapon(30, 50);
                weapon[] weaponArray1 = new weapon[3];
                for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
                weaponArray1[i] = testWeapon;
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have put a method inside a method. You can't do that.

Remove `init` from `Main` and put it on its own:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    init();  
}

public static void init()
{
    weapon testWeapon = new weapon(30, 50);
    weapon[] weaponArray1 = new weapon[3];
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
        weaponArray1[i] = testWeapon;
}
```

Also, I can't see where you've declared a weapon class. You'll have to make sure you put that class in this file or import the namespace where it is declared with a using statement.

Comment: And be sure to define `weapon` or to import the namespace it's defined in.

Comment: the only answer that would compile

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a method in a method. You need to declare them separately. Here's what you probably meant to do:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Beetlegeuse_intrusion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            init();
        }
        public void init()
        {
            weapon testWeapon = new weapon(30, 50);
            weapon[] weaponArray1 = new weapon[3];
            for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
            weaponArray1[i] = testWeapon;
        }

    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a method inside another one.

Declare the `Init()` at the class level:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Beetlegeuse_intrusion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            Init();
        }

        static void Init()
        {
            weapon testWeapon = new weapon(30, 50);
            weapon[] weaponArray1 = new weapon[3];
            for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
            weaponArray1[i] = testWeapon;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Add `void` to the `Init` method